# Microsoft Band 2 GPS Info

Tags: microsoft-band

Does anyone know if there is a way to access GPS data from the Microsoft Band 2 using the SDK? I've been playing around in Android Studio but don't see it listed in the Sensors part of the packages that Microsoft provided to developers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there is actually no way to access the GPS using the SDK.

You have only the following **sensors** available:

- Accelerometer
- Gyroscope
- Distance
- Heart Rate
- Pedometer
- Skin
- Temperature
- Band Contact
- Calories Provides
- Galvanic Skin
- Response (Microsoft Band 2 only)
- RR Interval (Microsoft Band 2 only)
- Ambient Light (Microsoft Band 2 only)
- Barometer (Microsoft Band 2 only)
- Altimeter (Microsoft Band 2 only)

Source: http://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf

"Waypoints" from activities could be retrieved from the [Microsoft Health API](https://developer.microsoftband.com/cloudAPI).

Answer (score 2):

The Band SDK does not expose its GPS sensor. The application using the Band SDK is typically running on a mobile device that has its own GPS sensor (accessible to the application) as well as a far larger battery than the Band.  Therefore, there is generally little reason for an application to use the GPS sensor of the Band.

Comment: Wow i Just got a Band and one of the primary reasons I bought it was for the GPS tracking information.  I wanted to write an app to track fishing locations so I wouldn't have to manually enter them into my fish finder.  This is incredibly disappointing and very short sighted.

Comment: Remember that you don't write apps *for* the Band; you write them for the phone which connects *to* the Band. If that phone has GPS then there's very little benefit to streaming the Band's GPS data vs. the phone's given the difference in battery size. The alternative, if the Band will be used while fishing without a phone nearby, is to start an activity (e.g. bike) that captures GPS when you head out. Then, when you're back, you can (or, will eventually be able to) use the Cloud API to extract the GPS waypoints from the activity. Remember, though, that the Band only gets 4-5 hours of GPS.